# Php 2D array into javascript array in highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, highcharts

I have a 2 dimensional array in php

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [date] => 16/06/2014 [total_booking] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [date] => 16/06/2014 [total_booking] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [date] => 16/06/2014 [total_booking] => 1 ) [3] => Array ( [date] => 17/06/2014 [total_booking] => 1 ) [4] => Array ( [date] => 18/06/2014 [total_booking] => 1 ) [5] => Array ( [date] => 18/06/2014 [total_booking] => 1 ) )
```

i want to use this array in highcharts as date in x-axis and total booking in y charts,
how to convert this array into javascript array.please help.

Comment: use json_encode($array); before sending it to javascript.

Comment: @iamde_coder can u please post as answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377570/how-to-use-json-encode http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914165/json-encode-and-highcharts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20918561/highcharts-php-json-correct-data-format

Answer (score 1):

use `json_encode($array);` before sending it to javascript.

Comment: can you please elaborate to how to use this json in highcharts.ie; dates in xaxis and total_booking in yaxis